# Issues with query parameters and lazy-loaded modules after upgrading Angular v8 to v15

Tags: angular

Our team recently upgraded our Angular project from v8.3 to v15.2.5 following the Angular upgrade guide. Our routing modules are lazy loaded, and we followed the upgrade guide to make sure the lazy loaded children imports were updated.

Now, we're having an issue where it looks like our routes that use query parameters are not getting properly decoded.

For example, the following URL:

/webforms/data-report%3Fcode%3D00&param%3D001

We are expecting the URL to be parsed as:

/webforms/data-report/?code=00&param=001

We've tried the following to fix the issue:

Checked the routing configuration to make sure that the query parameters are properly defined.
Checked the lazy-loaded modules to make sure that the routes are being imported correctly.
Restarted the Angular development server.

However, we have not been able to fix the issue.